# Is PostgreSQL or MySQL more popular with Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql

In absolute terms, Postgres has more features and has been used at scale by Instagram, etc. while MySQL has a much bigger user base and has been used at scale by likes of Facebook, Quora, etc. But how about in combination with NodeJS?

Which is more popular with NodeJS?

Comment: _2) easier to setup, and 3) better for scaling out (not up)_ was removed from the question. I hope it will no longer draw opinion based answers. It should be relatively objective and experience based to answer which is more popular with NodeJS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. MySQL is probably more popular, solely in terms of userbase. (You sorta answered this yourself)
2. MySQL probably has more examples around the net which could help make things easier to set up. You'll probably also find MySQL more likely to come preloaded on a VPS if that's the sort of route you're taking. However setting up PostgreSQL on your server is not difficult, and there is plenty of documentation available.
3. It really depends on what your intentions are with your data. Digital Ocean wrote a nice concise comparison of MySQL and PostgreSQL found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems)

As far as how these play with node.js, in my experience the node modules for [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) and [MySQL](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) are equally pleasant to work with. Ultimately its more about picking the database that suits your data and what you want to do with your data. Then deciding how it fits into your node stack.

Comment: Do you know what is the https://node-postgres.com/ equivalent for `mysql`?